# Generating an XML file for textual data with a shell script on Linux

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create file.xml, I have a city.txt file with 1000 cities, one city name per line.

The file.xml should have this format (code block) for each city from city.txt

```
        <ss:Row ss:Height ="22">
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">CITY-FROM-TEXT-FILE-LINE-1</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">CALIFORNIA</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">CA</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
            <ss:Cell>
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">xx</ss:Data>
            </ss:Cell>
        </ss:Row>
```

What would be the best way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: I think shell would be best, can you help me with the code please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `awk` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    print "<ss:Row ss:Height='22'>"
}

{
    print "<ss:Cell>"
    print "<ss:Data ss:Type='String'>" $0 "</ss:Data>"
    print "</ss:Cell>"
}

END{
    print "</ss:Row>"    
}
```

To run this script:

```
$ awk -f xml.awk city.txt
```

Comment: The output should have all the rows as in the sample code, the whole code should be one block and only the CITY-FROM-TEXT-FILE-LINE-1 should change in every block.